# jQuery - Bubbles Conversation Layout

Tags: jquery

I need to implement the following layout structure in some web site:

[image]

As you can see, in this conversation there are 3 participants. Every line that a participant say is in a bubble. Every participant has different color bubble. All the bubbles for a participant have the same distance from the left.

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that implements this layout structure (or a similiar layout structure). This plugin should support at least 2 and 3 participants, but an option for more would be great.

If no such plugins exists, how can I implement this? I mean, how can I calculate the width of each bubble (depending on the participants count) and the margin-left for each bubble?

Thanks!

Comment: And what (x)html mark-up are you using?

Comment: @alon its some kind of tags where we give different css class names to different sectionss, maintain four or five classes and apply them dynamically //

Comment: @david looks like you are also spending today at stackoverflow?? where do you work david?

Comment: Does it need to be able to add participants mid-conversation?

Comment: @gov: I work for the [NHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Health_Service) (as an [ODP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_department_practitioner)), this web malarkey's just personal interest. Though if you've an interest in engaging me for a consulting gig... =p

Comment: @Alon is there anything further you need to solve your problem and officially accept an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created [a simple HTML and CSS example](http://jsfiddle.net/gZNs8/1/) using margins and rounded corners, with reasonably semantic markup.

**Edit**: I've created an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/gZNs8/3/) that uses jQuery to dynamically calculate how many people are in the conversation and set the margins appropriately. I've written it as a function so that you can call the function on some later event (when a new person joins the conversation) to automatically adjust the sizes.

I tried to get it to work more cleanly using the [GlobalStylesheet Plug-in](http://www.burnbright.co.nz/globalstylesheet-jquery-plugin/), but either that plug-in doesn't work with 1.4.x, or it doesn't work with JSFiddle, or I was using it improperly. So this uses 'standard' jQuery practice of explicitly setting/updating the styles per element.

Oh, and I moved the blockquote citation into a standard HTML4 [`cite`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-CITE) element so that you can style it with old IE. :p

Comment: **+1** Nice use of `content` there. No IE support though, obviously

Comment: @Eric but nice degradation anyway I guess.

Comment: @Trufa: Not particularly. IE7 users will just get coloured rectangles with text. No borders or participant names. Just text.

Comment: @Eric , along is not looking for rounded courners solution right , rounder corners can be done in many ways.../// the position of divs dynamically is main issue here

Comment: Oh, +1, that's fantastic! And *way* cleaner than my `dl` attempt. =)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! I didn't actually thought this is possible without JavaScript. But I need IE support anyway, any optionally more participants support :( How can I implement this in JavaScript (+jQuery)?

Comment: @Alon I've updated the answer to allow for arbitrary numbers of participants. All you need to set in the CSS are the colors for the maximum number of possible participants.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do something like this:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/NBHBD/1/

Assign a class to each one, and every time you generate it, simply assign that class.

Is this what you ment?

EDIT: If you want to do it with jquery, maybe you could use the the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

EDIT 2: Maybe you could adapt this plugin too, it is cross browser!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one implementation:

#### xhtml:

```
<dl>
    <dt class="participantOne">Participant One</dt>
    <dd class="participantOne">This is something from the first particpant.</dd>

    <dt class="participantTwo">Participant Two</dt>
    <dd class="participantTwo">Lorem ipsum</dd>
    <dd class="participantTwo">dolor sit amet. And so forth.</dd>

    <dt class="participantThree">Participant Three</dt>
    <dd class="participantThree">Something or other</dd>

    <dt class="participantOne">Participant One</dt>
    <dd class="participantOne">Yadda yadda.</dd>

    <dt class="participantThree">Participant Three</dt>
    <dd class="participantThree">Blah? With other text...</dd>
</dl>
```

#### css:

```
dt,
dd {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
dt {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 10px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 5px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 10px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 5px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 10px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 5px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 10px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 5px 10px yellow, 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

dt:after {
    content: " says: ";
}

dd {
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}

dd + dd {
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: dashed;
}

.participantOne {
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.participantTwo {
    margin-left: 1em;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
.participantThree {
    margin-left: 2em;
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jPXTc/).

Comment: Nice use of shadows and especially definition list for the conversation. (I'd +1 you if I had any more votes today.) Note that your CSS doesn't show borders on FF. Perhaps you consider relying on experimental CSS extensions bad form?

Comment: @Phrogz, Firefox 3.6.12 (Win XP SP3) is showing borders. Albeit not the **rounded** -borders. I don't really think there's anything wrong with using 'experimental' css, it serves to reward those with better browsers with a better visual experience; and does no real *harm* to those with, uh...for *example*, IE.

Comment: @Phrogz, also [`-moz-border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;` takes care of implementing the curved borders](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jPXTc/2/) with no particular problems.